# Get the name of the file that is currently compiled (with CMake)

Tags: gcc, dependencies, cmake, cross-compiling

I'm currently trying to cross compile a project using CMake.
I would like to output the dependencies of each compile file thanks to the -MF option of GCC. But this option need a filename to output.

`SET ( CMAKE_C_FLAGS "-mcpu=${CPU} -march=${CPU_ARCH} -O0 -MMD -MF ${XXXXXX}.d" )`

I'm looking for that XXXXXX variable name that will give me the name of the currently compiled file. Or any other way that will allow me to output a dependency file.

Thanks !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you don't need `-MMD -MF file` if your want use input file name, just use `-MD` instead

> -MD
>
> -MD is equivalent to -M -MF file, except that -E is not implied. The driver determines file based on whether an -o option is given. If it is, the driver uses its argument but with a suffix of .d, **otherwise it take the basename of the input file** and applies a .d suffix.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I ended up doing.